# How to access properties of Python super classes e.g. via __class__.__dict__?

Tags: python, reflection, properties, parent, introspection

How can I get all property names of a python class **including those properties inherited from super classes**?

```
class A(object):
  def getX(self):
    return "X"
  x = property(getX)

a = A()
a.x
'X'

class B(A):
  y = 10

b = B()
b.x
'X'

a.__class__.__dict__.items()
[('__module__', '__main__'), ('getX', <function getX at 0xf05500>), ('__dict__', <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>), ('x', <property object at 0x114bba8>), ('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>), ('__doc__', None)]
b.__class__.__dict__.items()
[('y', 10), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('__doc__', None)]
```

How can I access properties of a via b?
Need: "Give me a list of all *property* names from b including those inherited from a!"

```
>>> [q for q in a.__class__.__dict__.items() if type(q[1]) == property]
[('x', <property object at 0x114bba8>)]
>>> [q for q in b.__class__.__dict__.items() if type(q[1]) == property]
[]
```

I want to get results from the first (a), when working with the second (b), but current only can get an empty list. This also should work for another C inherited from B.

Comment: Note that `y` is not a property, it's just an integer. Do you want all class variables which are not functions perhaps?

Comment: Instead of having `getX`, have `get_x` if you care about Python style ([PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), or if you don't need to be able to do the function call version (you will if you ever go setting a property via `super()`---`super(...).x = 'Y'` will fail), just use `property` as a decorator, as `@property`, `def x(self): return 'X'`.

Comment: Thanks for those comments. I tried to create a simple example instead of my complex code and yes, I thereby did not think about PEP8. I do not care about that `y` because I only need the properties.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529192/is-there-a-way-to-access-dict-or-something-like-it-that-includes-base-clas

Answer (score 4):

You can use `dir()`:

```
for attr_name in dir(B):
    attr = getattr(B, attr_name)
    if isinstance(attr, property):
        print attr
```

Comment: Ok, I guess that works for me with a `print attr_name, attr.__get__(b)` at the end. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to help on #python.de@irc.freenode.net for a hint leading to an alternate answer:

    `for c in b.__class__.__mro__:
      if issubclass(c, A):
        for p in [q for q in c.__dict__.items() if type(q[1]) == property]:
          print p[0], '=', p[1].__get__(b)`

Comment: @user1156548: I don't think it's necessary to walk the MRO yourself.  Of course you *can*, but why *should* you?

Comment: using mro works like above dir() solution. Without both it is not working, because __class__.__dict__ does not contain properties of super classes. What would you suggest @sven-marnach

Comment: @user1156548: I suggest using `dir()`, since it is easier and does not show properties that have been overwritten by subclasses -- you wouldn't want them to appear twice, I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You can either use "dir", or you can follow all the classes that are contained in the tuple returned by "mro"  (method resolution order,given by the `__mro__` attribute on the class) - this later method is the only way of uncovering attributes that where later overriden by subclasses:

```
>>> class A(object):
...    b = 0
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   b = 1
... 
>>> for cls in B.__mro__:
...     for item in cls.__dict__.items():
...         if item[0][:2] != "__":
...            print cls.__name__, item
... 
B ('b', 1)
A ('b', 0)
>>>
```